# Need some help with JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

So I have a JQGrid on my page. I have actions binded to the `afterSaveCell` event on the grid - listed below:

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
    var data = {
        id: GetGUIDValue(),
        rowid: rowid,
        columnName: name,
        cellValue: val
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GetControllerUrl("UpdateScheduleRow", "Indications"),
        async: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (returnData) { /*ReloadGrid();*/
            if (iCol == 9) // index rate -- give enum later
            {
                if (returnData == "") {
                    alert('Cannot update Index Rate with blank value.');
                    fillRates();
                } else {
                    schedule.jqGrid('setCell', iRow, iCol, returnData);
                }
            } else {
                schedule.jqGrid('setCell', iRow, iCol, returnData);
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Error saving schedule row change: [Reason] ' + e.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

So what I want to have happen is, I want this code to be called for every single cell on every single row in the grid, every-time the grid loads, not just when a user updates one cell. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different event **afterInsertRow**  .This might solve your issue and call your code in this event

Comment: So will this trigger for each row everytime the grid is created?

Comment: yes it will. i have not tested but once i tried it was doing that but it is very bad on performance